# Add mfc to a project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have already started a project and would like to add forms to it with MFC. How do you do this? I tried setting it to use mfc but it still doesn't allow me to add mfc classes(it says it isn't an mfc project).

Also is there any GUI library that works sorta like .net? Maybe it is because I haven't used MFC too much but I don't care for how it does events.

Comment: I suggest splitting this into two different questions. It's a bit confusing what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't too late then you should seriously consider using [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).  You'll get a rich UI, the ability to add/remove events at runtime (through the [Qt signals and slots mechanism](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/signalsandslots.html)) plus the code will build for Windows, Linux and the Mac.  I cannot recommend this framework highly enough (and I have used MFC since 1994 and WTL since 2001.)

You can get a Qt Visual Studio plugin or even consider their superb IDE [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools).

Comment: I am trying Qt but it is being as big of a pain as MFC at the moment. I am sure when I get it working it will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/). It's kind of like MFC, but most of the work is done at compile time, so you don't have to ship a big DLL with your app. I did most of my learning at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtl4mfc1.aspx).

Comment: Well that is 1 of my problems. I don't like the message map. I much rather be able to add and remove events at runtime.

Comment: You could write yourself an abstraction for that (using e.g. boost.function or signals) or look for one online.