# VC++ : Difference between “MFC application” & Win32 Project with "Use MFC" as a Shared DLL/Static Library

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, dll, mfc, win32com

Just started learning VC++, and in one of the video tutorial it initially shown and then skipped MFC wizard and started with win32 project and selected the "with Use MFC in a Shared DLL". So i checked the difference between the both (MFC & WIN32) in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821676/how-do-i-decide-whether-to-use-atl-mfc-win32-or-clr-for-a-new-c-project/821725#821725). There it said as "MFC builds upon Win32". Already two project types are there (MFC & WIN32). Then what is the meaning of "Use of MFC" in Win32 Project?

Comment: It simply skips the built-in project templates for MFC, the ones that auto-generate a *lot* of MFC code.  Using MFC from a Win32 project is fine, a tutorial probably prefers it that way so it can incrementally teach the basics.

Answer (score 0):

[MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications) is a library developed on top of Win32.
An MFC project can either link to the MFC static library or require the compiled e executable to run with the MFC dll alongside with it.
Win32 projects do not require MFC and using MFC is [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015049/how-to-add-mfc-support-to-existing-win32-c-project).